# CakePHP routing in pages controller

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I am creating a site with CakePHP, and I need to set some URLs for static pages, which are handled by the pages controller. Basically I want to have two different types of static pages, with the URLS

> mysyte.com/page

which should map to `app/views/pages/page.ctp` and

> mysite.com/special/page

which should map to `app/views/pages/special-page.ctp`. Note that in the first case page can be 'special' as well.

I am a bit lost with the routing I have to set up for this situation. I have tried to use the two routes

```
Router::connect(
    '/special/:mypage',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    array('pass' => array('mypage'), 'mypage' => '[a-z]+')
);
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

and in the pages controller

```
function display($page = null, $mypage = null) {
    if ($mypage) {
        $path = array('special-'. $mypage);
    }
    else {
        $path = func_get_args();
    }

    //The rest of the display action
}
```

The problem is that is seems that `:mypage` is passed as the first parameter in the action, which is `page`, and not as the `mypage` parameter.

How can I possibly fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have discovered that the pages controller already handles this situation, checking for page and subpage. The URL `mysite.com/special/mypage` points to `app/views/pages/special/mypage.ctp` with the only rule

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Comment: that is a very greedy route, best you keep it at the bottom or nothing else will work.

Comment: Yes, this is a static site, and everything is managed by the pages controller.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing only one parameter to the action via routing, that's why it's the first one - its the only one. Names don't really matter.

I would do it like this:

```
Router::connect(
  '/:page',
  array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
  array('pass' => array('page'), 'page' => '[a-z]+')
  ); 
Router::connect(
  '/special/:mypage',
  array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display_special'),
  array('pass' => array('page'), 'page' => '[a-z]+')
  );
```

Controller code:

```
function display($page) {}
function display_special($page) {}
```

But if you want your way, try this:

```
Router::connect(
  '/:special/:mypage',
  array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
  array('pass' => array('special', 'mypage'), 'mypage' => '[a-z]+')
  );
```

Comment: well, the point was to avoid having to write a second action in the page controller. But it turns out it is simpler, than that, as I explain in my answer.