# Routing search engine friendly URLs for PagesController in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I'm try to create search engine friendly URLs for the pages controller, i.e. `/about` instead of `/pages/about`.

I've tried setting up the following routes (at the bottom of routes.php):

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

and

```
Router::connect('/:page', array('controller' => 'pages',
  'action' => 'display'), array('pass' => array('page'), 'page' => '[a-z]+'));
```

Both properly match `/about`, `/support`, etc. However, failed when I had a action/method pair. For example, `/contact` should route to `PagesController->contact()`. However, the above routed it to `PagesController->display()`.

There has to be a way to accomplish this without making a specific route for each page. How can I create a route or set of routes that:

- Mimics the default route behavior for
  the PagesController. That is routes
  to display() unless a action/method
  pair exists.
- Does so with search engine friendly URL. That is coming from root `/` not `/pages`.
- Demonstrate both the `Router::connect()` and `Html->link()`

I have checked for examples in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org) and viewed other questions such as [CakePHP routing in pages controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154246/cakephp-routing-in-pages-controller). Nothing seems to satisfy the specification above.

Comment: `/*`? Are you using other controllers in your application besides PagesController?

Comment: Well, how would cake know if `/xyz` is supposed to invoke `XYZController->index()` and not `PagesController->xyz()`? That's why you have to explicitly list the pages is it not?

Comment: @webbiedave, I see where you're going. But there has to be some way to accomplish the route I've outlined above. Clearly I'm saying that `/*` is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a second route for the contact method call and put it before the more generic rule to match "everything [a-z] after /pages". Try that before your rule:

```
Router::connect('/contact', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'contact'));
```

Always keep in mind that the order of routes is important. The more generic a rule is the more will it match. So put more specific rules in front of the more generic ones.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the spec. I know I can manually make rules to map to each page. I'm trying to avoid that with a dynamic rule.